# Implement a ProgressBar for Loading a TabControl Tab.

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar, tabcontrol

I've been seeking lot of forums arround the web, trying to find a way to make my tabControl more appealing, by making a progressbar to make the program "look like" more fast and efficient.

My Goal: Get the .Refresh function from my tabControl in a progressbar, and while it's doing it's work, the tabControl is !Visible, in the end, the tabControl reappear with an Alpha (I'll seek that afterwards) from 0 to 100%.

Thanks for the support!

PS: Using V2010 C#.

---

*EDIT*

@Mitch Wheat: 1) To make it "look like" more efficient. 2) I simply have a TabControl and a progressbar, with lots of textfields in the tabControl. All I want is to make the tab load before actually showing.

@CharithJ: Even that, I still don't know how to know the progress of my TabControl (refresh feature).

@Mathias Lykkegaard Lore: It's easy to say "make your custom control", but even that I don't know how to get the refresh progress of my tabControl.. That is the point here, *get the refresh time of my TabControl.*

Comment: BTW, a progressbar won't  "make the program more fast and efficient." It just 'placates' the users.

Comment: What is taking so long to load your controls?  The refresh method of the tabcontrol won't send any kind of refresh status of your child controls-- it just tells the operating system it's time to redraw.  That is why Mitch is asking to see some code-- the issue isn't with the tab control, it's with your loading code.

Comment: 1) What is taking so long to load your controls? Answer: Two Groupbox with 10 textfields each, the user can see the groupbox loading, then the ten textfields. I want it to have a loading sequence to make it more appealing.
2) I have no code what's however. I only have designed my form using the toolbox.

Comment: Those 10 textfields shouldn't take any time to load what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by making your own custom control, that has a TabControl in it, and a normal ProgressBar. From here, you can then manage how everything (the progressbar, the tab-control loading and fading in) is done.

Here you can see more details regarding custom controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new form with a Progress bar control. Set the form Size appropriately in order to make it looking good.
2. `ShowDialog(this)` in the SelectedTagChanged event or when the Tab refreshing.

In this way you have more control because you show your own Small Form with a Process Bar.

EDIT : When there is a top most form that avoids user activities when the tab is refreshing. There are no ready made refresh functionalities with TabPages for your requirements. You have to implement your own refresh logic.